# VBA copy paste codes does not pasting anything

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

Can someone please let me know why my code is not pasting anything from my source data to my destination file?
The objectives of this code are to select rows that satisfy certain criteria, copy-pastes it into another workbook, The code is shown below:

```
 

Sub Copy_Source_LRE() 

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

Workbooks.Open _

"C:\Users\sjiang\OneDrive - Canada Pension Plan Investment Board\Desktop\IOA Exposure\AAPAF_strategy_loadings_2019-04-01_2020-04-01 (2).csv"

Worksheets("AAPAF_strategy_loadings_2019-04").Activate

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Workbooks("AAPAF_strategy_loadings_2019-04-01_2020-04-01 (2).csv").Sheets("AAPAF_strategy_loadings_2019-04").Activate

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

For Each d In Array("4/1/2019", "5/1/2019", "6/3/2019", "7/1/2019", "8/1/2019", "9/2/2019", _

"10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/2/2019", "1/2/2020", "2/3/2020", "3/2/2020") 

    If Cells(i, 2) = d And Cells(i, 3) = "Real Estate" And Cells(i, 4) = "Listed Real Estate" And Cells(i, 5) = "AAPAF_SA" Then

    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 12)).Select

    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open _
    "C:\Users\sjiang\OneDrive - Canada Pension Plan Investment Board\Desktop\IOA Exposure\pull data.xlsm"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
'ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
Next d

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This is a really easy and basic way that I use all the time to copy data into new workbooks. In this example I'm copying a named range called "MasterData" into a new blank workbook. Then I save that new book with a password and re-activate the current workbook.

```
Dim newfilename As String
newfilename = "/Users/" & userName & "/Desktop/savedWorkbook.xlsx"
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Datasheet").Select
Range("MasterData").Copy
NewBook.Activate
NewBook.Sheets(1).Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=newfilename, Password:="examplepassword", AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
NewBook.Close (True)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I've redone the code for you as the major problem was related to a loop that is not really necessary. The best/fast way to apply those criteria and extract the data is using a filter to apply them, so copy the visible cells without the hidden (unmatching) lines and then open the second file where you need to past info, find next blank line below selection and paste all lines at once.
I'm pasting the code below (with comments) and also saved a zip file with 3 files (code, info, database) that might reflect your working files, link below.

VBS code:

```
Sub Copy_Source_LRE()
Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Wks1.xlsx" 'change the path and name here

Worksheets(1).Activate
Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

datar = Range(Cells(LastRow, 12), Cells(1, 1)).Address 'data range

Range(datar).Select
Selection.AutoFilter 'create a filter,then use the criteria you need

ActiveSheet.Range(datar).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
Array("4/1/2019", "5/1/2019", "6/3/2019", "7/1/2019", "8/1/2019", "9/2/2019", _
"10/1/2019", "11/1/2019", "12/2/2019", "1/2/2020", "2/3/2020", "3/2/2020"), Operator:=xlFilterValues 'your dates array can be update here

ActiveSheet.Range(datar).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Real Estate", Operator:=xlAnd

ActiveSheet.Range(datar).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Listed Real Estate", Operator:=xlAnd

ActiveSheet.Range(datar).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="AAPAF_SA", Operator:=xlAnd

Range(datar).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Range(datar).Rows.Count - 1, Range(datar).Columns.Count).Select 'resize selection to remove the header
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 'select visible cells only


Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Wks2.xlsx" 'change the path and name here

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select 'goes to the last row on column A the goes another one - 1st empty
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True 'close and save your  database
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close without saving your csv file

End Sub
```

link to files/code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zL_TwclHR4lrNhKB1xODGAmliPHM1r3K/view?usp=sharing

If the solution matches you need please consider as solution. Regards!